# Bloquear downloads de vídeo de site

Tags: php

Eu tenho um site e dentro dele eu armazeno vídeos que são exibidos através do . Porém, se a pessoal conseguir o link do vídeo pelo Inspecionar Elemento ela consegue baixar o vídeo. Há alguma forma de eu bloquear o download de arquivos? Apenas a exibição do vídeo.

Comment: No fim não importa qual método você usa, se o usuário realmente quiser salvar o vídeo, basta ele filmar a tela. Isso tudo é tempo jogado fora.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Sim, é possível.

#### Maneiras

Uma das maneiras mais eficiente, é utilizar `DRM` para proteção dos vídeos.

Como não há uma descrição precisa do que é o `DRM (Digital Rights Management)`, algumas pessoas separa-o em 4 elementos.

1. Direitos digitais gerenciáveis
2. Encriptação
3. Gestão de licença
4. Player

### Direitos digitais gerenciáveis

Os direitos digitais gerenciáveis permitem uma ampla negociação do seu conteúdo, isso inclui compras, alugueis etc. Seja via *streamming* ou até mesmo *downloads* (Como é o caso de plataformas que já oferecem vídeos *offline*). Com eles vocês podem determinar quem tem autorização para acessar determinado conteúdo.

### Encriptação

Aqui é onde as tecnologia de `DRM` fazem para proteger seu conteúdo. Essa criptografia pode ocorrer antes ou durante do *streamming*. E, evidentemente, antes do *download*.

Dessa forma apenas quem possuir a chave de acesso poderá visualizar o conteúdo.

### Gestão de Licença

Nessa área as tecnologias de `DRM` ficam encarregadas de verificar as chaves de acesso e os dispositivos do usuário.

### Player

Nesse elemento, o *player* fica responsável por se comunicar com o servidor responsável por gerenciar as chaves.

Alguns navegadores utiliza a *API Javascript* **[Media Source Extensions MSE](https://web.dev/media-mse-basics/)** e a extensão **[Encrypted Media Extensions EME](https://web.dev/media-eme/)**

---

### Media Source Extensions (MSE)

Esta *API* é responsável por gerir o fluxo para transmissão dos segmentos¹.
A `MSE` dar-te-á suporte para uma *transmissão adaptativa*², *Splicing* adaptável, Mudança de tempo, Controle de desempenho e tamanho de download.

O funcionamento é bem simples:

1. Os dados são solicitados via requisição;
2. Após isso são enviados para o [Response.ArrayBuffer();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/arrayBuffer)
3. Que, por sua vez, envia para o [MediaSource.SourceBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/SourceBuffer);
4. Finalmente é executado na *tag* `audio` ou `video` do *HTML5*.

[image: "Fluxo de dados básicos do MSE: Requisição > Envio para Response > Tratamento com MediaSource > Execução com as tag audio ou vídeo"]
<sub>(fonte: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/mse/images/basic-mse-flow.png))</sub>

### Encrypted Media Extensions (EME)

A *EME* é uma extensão recomendada pela [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-encrypted-media-20170918/), a proposta dela, a grosso modo, é estender o [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) para fornecer algumas *apis* para controle da reprodução de conteúdo criptografado.

Para informações técnicas recomendo dá uma lida na proposta [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-encrypted-media-20170918/)

---

### Como funciona o *DRM*

O funcionamento pode ser resumido nos passos abaixo (para proteção antes do *streaming*):

*Resumido:*

1. Conversão dos arquivos (*ffmpeg* e *mp4box* são exemplos de ferramentas)
2. Verifica as chaves de acesso
3. Gera a licença necessária
4. Executa, no player, os segmentos com a licença gerada.

*Detalhado:*

[image: Funcionamento do DRM]

---

### Como esses vídeos são divididos em segmentos?

Normalmente o pessoal usa o [HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) da *Apple* ou [MPEG-DASH](https://web.archive.org/web/20220122080919/https://www.encoding.com/mpeg-dash/). Nesta opção você pode utilizar o [Bento4](https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4dash/) para essa função.

---

### Vale a pena investir em DRM?

Depende do seu conteúdo. Caso você realmente queira, vale muito a pena.

Enquanto eu escrevia essa resposta, um usuário comentou sobre o usuário filmar o conteúdo. Será mesmo que isso vai acontecer? A resposta é simples, isso vai acontecer.

Porém, em um post sobre [Tecnologias de Vídeo](https://blog.schoolofnet.com/tecnologias-de-video-entenda-como-funcionam-e-qual-delas-implementamos-com-nosso-novo-player/), o Wesley William citou o fato do pessoal até poder gravar. Mas será que o pessoal vai realmente ter disposição para gravar e jogar na net? No caso da School Of Net, acredito que tenha diminuído bastante a pitaria.

Um dos comentário é referente a isso. O usuário informou que antes da proteção conseguia baixar, depois dela, não foi mais possível.

### Alternativas

Uma alternativa é utilizar marca d'água nos vídeos ([*exemplo*](https://web.archive.org/web/20220708103259/https://www.safestream.com/#video), isso pode ser gerado automaticamente com o *ffmpeg*, mas há um custo de processamento de dados para fazer isso.

### Links Úteis

*Links que não foram citados da resposta e que acho interessante a leitura*

- https://bitmovin.com
- http://clappr.io/
- https://drmtoday.com/drm-players/
- http://www.widevine.com/
- https://www.microsoft.com/playready/
- https://blog.schoolofnet.com/2017/02/tecnologias-de-video-entenda-como-funcionam-e-qual-delas-implementamos-com-nosso-novo-player/
- https://safestream.com/#video

---

> <sup>Nota 1</sup>: Esses segmentos são vários "pedaços" do vídeo. Isso melhora a performance do carregamento. Informações técnicas podem ser encontradas [nesse artigo](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html).

> <sup>Nota 2</sup>: Transmissão adaptativa é a maneira como o *player* vai se adapta conforme o dispositivo ou à rede. Ou seja, caso a conexão esteja ruim, a qualidade do vídeo é afetada.

Comment: Há uma outra maneira de fazer isso também, de graça. Você pode informar ao servidor para permitir o acesso a determinado arquivo apenas se o `useragent` for igual à "PlayerDRM" ou pode verificar se a requisição tem terminado `header`. Isso só irá funcionar para quem não entende o funcionamento da web, a depender do teu público alvo, pode testar. Caso seja necessário posso adicionar outra resposta.

Comment: +1. Eu penso dessa forma: Se o conteúdo é relevante para ser armazenado ou distribuído, não importa a proteção, o usuário vai dar um jeito. Do contrário, caso o interesse seja minimo em salvar o vídeo e o usuário não consiga, ele nem vai perder o tempo tentando gravar, então na teoria seria eficaz, mas se o interesse dele é tão baixo, não vejo motivos para perder muito tempo fazendo toda essa implementação.

Comment: @Raizant como não sei o conteúdo dele vou pegar algumas plataformas que conheço. O Alura, por exemplo, posta 15 videos-aulas de 12 mins/cada. Pouquíssimas pessoas estariam dispostas a gravar o conteúdo somente para jogar na internet. Eles tem dezenas de cursos. Isso seria muito cansativo. O conteúdo pode ser interessante, mas logo, logo o cara vai cansar de fazer isso. Agora ele tem que se perguntar sobre os custos, se realmente vai a pena para o conteúdo dele. Inclusive, ele pode optar por utilizar serviços como o https://safestream.com/#video que adiciona uma marca d'´agua c/ infos no vídeo.